# Beginner programmer, functions not working

Tags: python, function

beginner here, im currently creating a coffee shop program in pycharm where the costumer inputs the product and then the program sums up all of the price. Im trying to loop the program with the use of functions so the customer can order a many as they want. But when i inputted def main(): in the program, the program under the function does not continue when i run it and i made sure that the codes under the function are indented. Any help would be appreciated thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKi9B.jpg)

here's the code, sorry

```
print("Good day!, welcome to Avenida's coffee shop")
print("Before i take you order, may i know your name?")
name = input("Input name here: ")
print(
    "Hello there " + name + "!, to get started we sell different kinds of food here, we sell coffee, frappe, cake, and pastas")
print("To access our menu, input your preferred food below")

def main():
    total_price = 0
    category = input("Input your preferred food here: ")
    if category.lower() == "coffee":
        print("Coffee Menu:")
        print("1 Cappuccino   = $2")
        print("2 Espresso     = $2.50")
        print("3 Latte        = $3")
        coffee_input = input("Input the assigned number of the coffee that you would like to order: ")
        if int(coffee_input) == 1:
            print("How many cappuccino would you like to order?")
            coffee_quantity = input("Input here: ")
            coffee_total = float(coffee_quantity) * 2
            print("That would be $" + str(coffee_total))
            total_price = total_price + coffee_total
        if int(coffee_input) == 2:
            print("How many espresso would you like to order?")
            coffee_quantity = input("Input here: ")
            coffee_total = float(coffee_quantity) * 2.50
            print("That would be $" + str(coffee_total))
            total_price = total_price + coffee_total
        if int(coffee_input) == 3:
            print("How many latte would you like to order?")
            coffee_quantity = input("Input here: ")
            coffee_total = float(coffee_quantity) * 3
            print("That would be $" + str(coffee_total))
            total_price = total_price + coffee_total
```

Comment: Try posting the codes here, it helps in resolving your problem.

Comment: please post your code here. And tell us where exactly you are having issues.

Comment: can you tell us the expected result?

Comment: Picture doesn't count as code

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the end of your code, outside of your `main` loop. You defined a function called `main`, but you did not execute it, thus the issue.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thankyou so much, the function is properly running now

Comment: You are most welcomed. All the best! =)

Comment: @Dreyg Happy that you solved your problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.